# MS Access Web App: Link existing view to table

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I have created a new view ("form") in my Access Web App using the menu buttons to create a new view. The view is bound to a table in my database. Running Access on my computer, I can select the view from the navigation panel on the left.

Now I would like to have a link to my view appear at the top of the page in the Web App. Much like the default List and Datasheet view that are created automatically for every new table.
How can I create a link to my view, so that I can select it when running my Web App in the browser?

(And in general: where's a good place to find documentation and help regarding Access Web Apps. I'm having a hard time finding anything online)

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What entry point did you use to create this new view in your Access web app? If you used the Advanced button on the ribbon, that creates what we call a standalone view in your web app - a view that exists in the Navigation Pane in Access client. You can only open these types of views using macros.

In order to "associate" an existing standalone view to the View Selector at the top of the navigation, right-click the view name in the Navigation Pane and select `Duplicate`. a dialog box will appear that allows you to create an identical copy of the view and "associate" it with a particular table. It will then appear as a link in the View Selector. You can then delete the original view if you want.